# Amazon Quicksight Functions - SQL JOIN equivalent

Tags: amazon-web-services, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I am looking for a functionality similar to SQL LEFT JOIN in Amazon Quicksight using functions and filters.

I have a table with  userID and LoginTime. Trying to calculate users who logged in for the first time for this month. ie Users for this month MINUS/LEFT JOIN users for previous months

Something along the lines of

> not contains(logins, unique(logins between dateTrunc('YYYY',
> dateAdd('YYYY', -5, now())) and dateTrunc('MM', dateAdd('MM', -1,
> now()))))

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new calculated field called "FirstLoginThisMonth" to find the minimum login time for each user:

`minOver({LoginTime}, [{userID}], PRE_AGG)`

Then create another calculated field called "IsFirstLoginThisMonth" :

`ifelse(dateDiffTrunc('MM', {FirstLoginThisMonth}, {LoginTime}) = 0, 'Yes', 'No')`

It will compare the login time with the first login time of the user for the month and returns "Yes" if it's the first login this month, otherwise "No".

Then apply a filter using the "IsFirstLoginThisMonth" field with the filter condition:

`"IsFirstLoginThisMonth" = 'Yes'`